# Nested Bulleted lists in Novacode docx

Tags: docx, nested-lists, novacode-docx

How can i create nested bulleted/Ordered lists with Novacode for docx?
I've done some research but couldn't find anything, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's not too late, I've just figured it out a couple hours ago

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string docPath = "PATH TO YOUR OUTPUT WORD DOCUMENT" ;

        var doc = DocX.Create(docPath);
        var l = doc.AddList("Item #1", 0, ListItemType.Bulleted, 0);
        doc.AddListItem(l, "Item #2");
        doc.InsertList(l);

        doc.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u for your reply. But i can't see the nested list here, AddList creates a list, addlistItem adds items to the list created and then insertlist add it to document, isin't?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the indent-level (parameter 2 of `DocX.AddList(...)` and parameter 3 of `DocX.AddListItem(...)`)

```cs
DocX doc = DocX.Create("filename.docx");

List list = doc.AddList("item 1", 0, ListItemType.Numbered);
doc.AddListItem(list, "item 2", 1);
doc.AddListItem(list, "item 3", 1);
doc.AddListItem(list, "item 4", 2);
doc.AddListItem(list, "item 5", 2);
doc.AddListItem(list, "item 6", 1);
doc.AddListItem(list, "item 7", 0);
doc.AddListItem(list, "item 8", 2);

doc.InsertList(list);
```

This produces:

[image]